# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object in my node file

Tags: node.js

New to Node, Please solve the error
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var productRoutes = require('./api/routes/product');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use('/products', productRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

`api/routes/product.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { 
  res.status(200).json({message: "Here we are handling the get request for the products"});
});
```

Comment: What the `productRoutes` contains - show us code.

Comment: Add you `api/routes/product` file content too in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change you `api/routes/product` code . will work fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Here we are handling the get request for the products"
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The reason was that you was not exporting your router to other file when you write `module.exports = router;` in file it will export.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
```

productRoutes should be a function with this paramters (req, res, next). It could be something like this:

```
app.use('/products', function(req, res, next) {
    // Do the things here
});
```

if you have any function like this in your productRoutes module, you could export that function and pass it as second parameter in app.use call

Comment: Here is the code in productRoutes

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Here we are handling the get request for the products"
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

If you're refactoring your routes and controllers, it's possible that early in one of your controllers you may list all your routes

```
router.post('/', GetProducts);
router.post('/add', AddProduct);
```

followed by

`module.exports = router;` <-- middleware function

but you may have overlooked an existing `module.exports` (from before your refactoring) at the end of the controller, which exports all the controller's functions:

`module.exports = { fxn1, fxn2, fxn3 };` <-- object

In that case, the later `module.exports` object would overwrite the earlier `module.exports` middleware function, and cause this error.